# Uploading image to google drive without file input field

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, google-drive-api

I need to upload an image to google drive via nodejs after cropping it by a image cropping library. Previously I was uploading images with file input field, so i can get buffer(using express-fileupload library) of the image in backend(nodejs). Now the problem is, after cropping I have image in the form of

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAA....
```

How to send images in this form to backend such that we could get buffer of that image so as to upload to google drive. Else could we upload this directly to google drive in frontend(javascript)? .I tried using FormData but I can get only string not buffer.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried to convert  image URL to buffer and upload to drive as we do in backend NodeJs. But I could not and don't know weather it will work. I'm wondering weather I could upload as a text file , but it seems so silly. Even I tried to manually assign image to file input field, and came to know that it's not possible. Any alternative please.

Comment: I tried with form data and it worked.But in backend im not getting buffer of the submited image , rather getting something like  ' ------WebKitFormBoundaryrdxcaeywmG7EOWuK\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"magei"\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA......'.. How to parse this like normal form data.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't forget to share the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

- It depends on how your backend and frontend are connected because you will be not able to transfer the image in this form to the backend using **HTTP POST**
  as the maximum size for a **HTTP POST** is **64KB**
- However it is very possible to send the image in a blob form to your backend using a **WebSocket/WebRTC** Library like **Socket.io**
- For example lets take a express backend and a traditional static html homepage with some javascript
  *example*

```
    //my webpage which has the blob this is some browser javascript connected to a html file
    //Hosted on http://localhost:3000
          var base64data
    //I have a cake.png in my static directory
            fetch("cake.png")
                .then(response => response.blob())
                .then(blob => {
                    const fileReader = new FileReader();
                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                    fileReader.onloadend = function() {
                        base64data = fileReader.result;
                    }
                })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
          const socket = io("http://localhost:4000")
            socket.on('connect',()=>{
    //Sent this blob to the server
              socket.emit('blob',base64data)
            })
```

My nodejs file which has a socket.io and drive api
Socket.io Server hosted on http://localhost:4000

```
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const google = require("googleapis");
const io = new Server(4000, {
    cors: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"],
    },
});
/*Initialize the drive
 *......
 *......
 */
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("blob", (blob) => {
        drive.files.create({
            requestBody: {
                name: "image.png",
                mimeType: "image/png",
            },
            media: {
                mimeType: "image/png",
                body: blob,
            },
        });
    });
});
```

There fore the blob can be used as a input for **body** while creating files